# Calculation is recursive

Tags: vbscript

I have one program, which is working fine in simulation window, but when it come across actual source, it gives an error/bad calculation stating that calculation is recursive.

Program is

```
If [Root.UNITNAME.RX1000_PREV_RECIPE.Value] = [Parent.RECIPENAME.Value] And [Root.UNITNAME.RX1000.BSTS.Value] = "END" Then
    [Result] = CDate((([Root.UNITNAME.RX1000.ENDTIME.Value] + 19800) / 86400) + 25569)
Else
    [Result] = ""
End If
```

Kindly note that all things ends with `.value` are my tags and `[Root.UNITNAME.RX1000_PREV_RECIPE.Value]` this is my another calculation tag which I want to use in this calculation.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. There is nothing inherently wrong with the code snippet you posted (although I wouldn't recommend using variable names like that). Also include the complete error (message text, error number, line number, etc.).

Comment: This isn't standard VBScript what are you using it in, looks like [tag:sap] or [tag:hp-uft]?

Comment: Yes, it is not a standard VBScript. it is using one of application (industrial Application) based console window on which program is written for that particular tag.

Comment: What is `[Root.UNITNAME.RX1000.ENDTIME.Value]`? A Date, an Integer, a Double??

Comment: Hi all, I got the solution. actually this is industrial application based console window programming. i was writing this program in the same tag as that of output tag thats why it was giving an error. Now i have added just [result.tag name] instead of using just tag name.   it solved my problem.... thank you